# How to query in SQL tables of Dynamics 365 on premises for audit changes of specific field by old and new value

Tags: crm, audit, dynamics-365

I need to query Audit log information like
" When and by whom the Field1 was changed from "oldValue1" to "NewValue1" ".
This should be done in SQL database of Dynamics 365 on premises.

I have found Audit table, but I can not find in it information on filed name and new value, can someone help me with that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you managed to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[You can follow this article to query audit table via sql](https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.com/2015/02/ms-crm-audit-database-table-details.html)

Recommended way is using SDK of crm, [Here is using API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/auditing/retrieve-audit-data?tabs=webapi)

In addition there are XRMToolBox Plugins wherein you do not need to code or query, it is a tool and will give you all the info.

https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/AuditHistoryExtractor/
https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MESquare.XrmToolBox.AuditExplorer/
https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/BDK.XrmToolBox.UserAuditViewer/